# First few layers are now printing very badly

Tags: print-quality, creality-ender-3, troubleshooting

Machine type is an Ender 3 pro with the 4.2.7 board, the latest Marlin bugfix code, latest BLTouch 3.1, latest all metal extruder feeder hardware, Capricorn Bowden PTFE Tubing.

This really started after having a bad clog in the extruder, thus had to take it apart, clean the clog and put it back together.  Nothing changed in any of the axes gantries it just all of a sudden started printing the first few layers very poorly. In fact anything that is only say less than 3 mm tall won't print hardly at all.

First layer print for bed leveling does print well, and the bed is pretty level. PLA used as filament, temperatures are 200 °C for the nozzle and 60 °C for the bed.

[image: PhotoOfBadFirstFewLayers]

Comment: That looks like cooking the bottom area... what#s the temperature of the bed? And the material? 200 head/60 bed would be typical PLA.

Comment: Sorry, missed that vital info!!  I've updated the original post, but it was 200 nozzle/60 bed.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I guess if I were more experienced I would have checked this earlier.  I tried everything almost tore my printer apart and rebuilt.  One more testing of a cube and the filament broke.  I became suspicious and replaced the filament with another brand and voila, no more printing issues!  Looks like it was the filament.

Comment: You may be able to recover the filament, if you have sufficient volume to justify it, by dehydrating it. Some filament turns bad from absorbing too much moisture and will print again after drying.

Comment: oh wow, yeah, hardly any has been used, 99% is still left.  I'll google on how to dry filament.